# OpenGL: Draw spheres on .obj vertices

Tags: opengl, geometry, vertices

I've loaded a .obj cube in my scene and I want to draw a sphere on every vertices (vertices + origin).

```
##
##  Three-D Library generated .obj file
##  cube
##

mtllib cube.mtl
usemtl red

# 0 materials

v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
# 8 vertices
```

In my draw() function:

```
if(spheres){
    i=0, j=0;
    while (1){
            printf("%d : %f %f %f\n", j, model->vertices[i], model->vertices[i+1], model->vertices[i+2]);
            glTranslatef(model->vertices[i], model->vertices[i+1], model->vertices[i+2]);
            glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            glutSolidSphere(0.4, 5, 5);
            if(j >= model->numvertices)
                break;
            i=i+3;
            j++;
        }
}
```

where 'model' is

```
GLMmodel*  model;               /* glm model data structure */
```

http://www.teina.org/TER_3DModeler/glm_8h-source.html

BUT when I draw them, they are not in correct positions.

In the picture above I draw them "manually":

```
glTranslatef(-1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glutSolidSphere(0.3, 5, 5);

glTranslatef(-1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glutSolidSphere(0.3, 5, 5);
```

with no success.

All code:

```
/*  
    gc_smooth.c
    Nate Robins, 1998
    Giulio Casciola, 2008

    Model viewer program.  Exercises the glm library.
*/

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "gltb.h"
#include "glm.h"
#include "dirent32.h"

#pragma comment( linker, "/entry:\"mainCRTStartup\"" )  // set the entry point to be main()

#define DATA_DIR "data/"
#define NUM_FRAMES 5

char*      model_file = NULL;       /* name of the obect file */
GLuint     model_list = 0;      /* display list for object */
GLMmodel*  model;               /* glm model data structure */
GLfloat    scale;               /* original scale factor */
GLfloat    smoothing_angle = 90.0;  /* smoothing angle */
GLfloat    weld_distance = 0.00001; /* epsilon for welding vertices */
GLboolean  facet_normal = GL_FALSE; /* draw with facet normal? */
GLboolean  bounding_box = GL_FALSE; /* bounding box on? */
GLboolean  spheres = GL_FALSE;
GLboolean  performance = GL_FALSE;  /* performance counter on? */
GLboolean  stats = GL_FALSE;        /* statistics on? */
GLuint     material_mode = 0;       /* 0=none, 1=color, 2=material, 3=texture */
GLint      entries = 0;         /* entries in model menu */
GLdouble   pan_x = 0.0;
GLdouble   pan_y = 0.0;
GLdouble   pan_z = 0.0;
char texnames[1][64] = {"foto_rgb.ppm"};
//char texnames[1][64] = {"grid.ppm"};
GLint w,h;
GLubyte* texture;


#define CLK_TCK 1000

#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#else
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#endif

float elapsed(void){
    static long begin = 0;
    static long finish, difference;

#if defined(_WIN32)
    static struct timeb tb;
    ftime(&tb);
    finish = tb.time*1000+tb.millitm;
#else
    static struct tms tb;
    finish = times(&tb);
#endif

    difference = finish - begin;
    begin = finish;

    return (float)difference/(float)CLK_TCK;
}

void shadowtext(int x, int y, char* s) {
    int lines;
    char* p;

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), 
        0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    glRasterPos2i(x+1, y-1);
    for(p = s, lines = 0; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == '\n') {
            lines++;
            glRasterPos2i(x+1, y-1-(lines*18));
        }
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, *p);
    }
    glColor3ub(0, 128, 255);
    glRasterPos2i(x, y);
    for(p = s, lines = 0; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == '\n') {
            lines++;
            glRasterPos2i(x, y-(lines*18));
        }
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, *p);
    }
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void lists(void){
    GLfloat ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
    GLfloat diffuse[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0 };
    GLfloat specular[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat shininess = 65.0;

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, shininess);

    if (model_list)
        glDeleteLists(model_list, 1);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    /* generate a list */
    switch (material_mode)
    {
     case 0:
        if (facet_normal)
            model_list = glmList(model, GLM_FLAT);
        else
            model_list = glmList(model, GLM_SMOOTH);
     break;
     case 1:
        if (facet_normal)
            model_list = glmList(model, GLM_FLAT | GLM_COLOR);
        else
            model_list = glmList(model, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_COLOR);
     break;
     case 2:
        if (facet_normal)
            model_list = glmList(model, GLM_FLAT | GLM_MATERIAL);
        else
            model_list = glmList(model, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL);
     break;
     case 3:
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        model_list = glmList(model, GLM_TEXTURE);
//        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     break;
    }
}

void init(void){
    gltbInit(GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON);

    /* read in the model */
    model = glmReadOBJ(model_file);
    scale = glmUnitize(model);
    glmFacetNormals(model);
    glmVertexNormals(model, smoothing_angle);

    if (model->nummaterials > 0)
        material_mode = 2;

    /* create new display lists */
    lists();

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void reshape(int width, int height){
    gltbReshape(width, height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat)height / (GLfloat)width, 1.0, 128.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);
}

void display(void){
    static char s[256], t[32];
    static char* p;
    static int frames = 0;
    int i=0,j=0;

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(pan_x, pan_y, 0.0);

    gltbMatrix();

#if 0   /* glmDraw() performance test */
    swith(material_mode)
    {
     case 0:
        if (facet_normal)
            glmDraw(model, GLM_FLAT);
        else
            glmDraw(model, GLM_SMOOTH);
     break;
     case 1:
        if (facet_normal)
            glmDraw(model, GLM_FLAT | GLM_COLOR);
        else
            glmDraw(model, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_COLOR);
     break;
     case 2:
        if (facet_normal)
            glmDraw(model, GLM_FLAT | GLM_MATERIAL);
        else
            glmDraw(model, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL);
     break;
     case 3:
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glmDraw(model, GLM_TEXTURE );
//        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     break;
    }
#else
    glCallList(model_list);
#endif

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    if (bounding_box) {
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25);
        glutSolidCube(2.0);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    }

    if(spheres){
        //i=0, j=0;
        //while (1){
                printf("%d : %f %f %f\n", j, model->vertices[i], model->vertices[i+1], model->vertices[i+2]);
                glTranslatef(-1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000);
                glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                glutSolidSphere(0.3, 5, 5);
                glTranslatef(-1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000);
                glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                glutSolidSphere(0.3, 5, 5);
                //if(j >= model->numvertices)
                //    break;
                //i=i+3;
                //j++;
            //}
    }

    glPopMatrix();

    if (stats) {
        /* XXX - this could be done a _whole lot_ faster... */
        int height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
        sprintf(s, "%s\n%d vertices\n%d triangles\n%d normals\n"
            "%d texcoords\n%d groups\n%d materials",
            model->pathname, model->numvertices, model->numtriangles, 
            model->numnormals, model->numtexcoords, model->numgroups,
            model->nummaterials);
        shadowtext(5, height-(5+18*1), s);
    }

    /* spit out frame rate. */
    frames++;
    if (frames > NUM_FRAMES) {
        sprintf(t, "%g fps", frames/elapsed());
        frames = 0;
    }
    if (performance) {
        shadowtext(5, 5, t);
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    GLint params[2];

    switch (key) {
    case 'h':
        printf("help\n\n");
        printf("w         -  Toggle wireframe/filled\n");
        printf("c         -  Toggle culling\n");
        printf("n         -  Toggle facet/smooth normal\n");
        printf("b         -  Toggle bounding box\n");
        printf("r         -  Reverse polygon winding\n");
        printf("m         -  Toggle color/material/none/texture mode\n");
        printf("p         -  Toggle performance indicator\n");
        printf("s/S       -  Scale model smaller/larger\n");
        printf("t         -  Show model stats\n");
        printf("o         -  Weld vertices in model\n");
        printf("+/-       -  Increase/decrease smoothing angle\n");
        printf("W         -  Write model to file (out.obj)\n");
        printf("q/escape  -  Quit\n\n");
        break;

    case 't':
        stats = !stats;
        break;

    case 'p':
        performance = !performance;
        break;

    case 'm':
        material_mode++;
        if (material_mode > 3)
            material_mode = 0;
        printf("material_mode = %d\n", material_mode);
        lists();
        break;

    case 'd':
        glmDelete(model);
        init();
        lists();
        break;

    case 'w':
        glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, params);
        if (params[0] == GL_FILL)
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        else
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        break;

    case 'c':
        if (glIsEnabled(GL_CULL_FACE))
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        else
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        break;

    case 'b':
        bounding_box = !bounding_box;
        break;

    case 'n':
        facet_normal = !facet_normal;
        lists();
        break;

    case 'r':
        glmReverseWinding(model);
        lists();
        break;

    case 's':
        glmScale(model, 0.8);
        lists();
        break;

    case 'S':
        glmScale(model, 1.25);
        lists();
        break;

    case 'o':
        //printf("Welded %d\n", glmWeld(model, weld_distance));
        glmVertexNormals(model, smoothing_angle);
        lists();
        break;

    case 'O':
        weld_distance += 0.01;
        printf("Weld distance: %.2f\n", weld_distance);
        glmWeld(model, weld_distance);
        glmFacetNormals(model);
        glmVertexNormals(model, smoothing_angle);
        lists();
        break;

    case '-':
        smoothing_angle -= 1.0;
        printf("Smoothing angle: %.1f\n", smoothing_angle);
        glmVertexNormals(model, smoothing_angle);
        lists();
        break;

    case '+':
        smoothing_angle += 1.0;
        printf("Smoothing angle: %.1f\n", smoothing_angle);
        glmVertexNormals(model, smoothing_angle);
        lists();
        break;

    case 'W':
        glmScale(model, 1.0/scale);
        glmWriteOBJ(model, "out.obj", GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL);
        break;

    case 'R':
        {
            GLuint i;
            GLfloat swap;
            for (i = 1; i <= model->numvertices; i++) {
                swap = model->vertices[3 * i + 1];
                model->vertices[3 * i + 1] = model->vertices[3 * i + 2];
                model->vertices[3 * i + 2] = -swap;
            }
            glmFacetNormals(model);
            lists();
            break;
        }

     case 'v':
        {
            spheres = !spheres;
            /*printf("Il modello ha %u vertici \n", model->numvertices);
            int i=0, j=0;
            while (1){
                printf("%d : %f %f %f\n", j, model->vertices[i], model->vertices[i+1], model->vertices[i+2]);
                if(j >= model->numvertices)
                    break;
                i=i+3;
                j++;
            }*/
            break;
        }

    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void menu(int item){
    int i = 0;
    DIR* dirp;
    char* name;
    struct dirent* direntp;

    if (item > 0) {
        keyboard((unsigned char)item, 0, 0);
    } else {
        dirp = opendir(DATA_DIR);
        while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
            if (strstr(direntp->d_name, ".obj")) {
                i++;
                if (i == -item)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (!direntp)
            return;
        name = (char*)malloc(strlen(direntp->d_name) + strlen(DATA_DIR) + 1);
        strcpy(name, DATA_DIR);
        strcat(name, direntp->d_name);
        model = glmReadOBJ(name);
        scale = glmUnitize(model);
        glmFacetNormals(model);
        glmVertexNormals(model, smoothing_angle);

        if (model->nummaterials > 0)
            material_mode = 2;
        else
            material_mode = 0;

        lists();
        free(name);

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

static GLint      mouse_state;
static GLint      mouse_button;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    GLdouble model[4*4];
    GLdouble proj[4*4];
    GLint view[4];

    /* fix for two-button mice -- left mouse + shift = middle mouse */
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && glutGetModifiers() & GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT)
        button = GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON;

    gltbMouse(button, state, x, y);

    mouse_state = state;
    mouse_button = button;

    if (state == GLUT_DOWN && button == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON) {
        glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);
        glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);
        gluProject((GLdouble)x, (GLdouble)y, 0.0,
            model, proj, view,
            &pan_x, &pan_y, &pan_z);
        gluUnProject((GLdouble)x, (GLdouble)y, pan_z,
            model, proj, view,
            &pan_x, &pan_y, &pan_z);
        pan_y = -pan_y;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void motion(int x, int y){
    GLdouble model[4*4];
    GLdouble proj[4*4];
    GLint view[4];

    gltbMotion(x, y);

    if (mouse_state == GLUT_DOWN && mouse_button == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON) {
        glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);
        glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);
        gluProject((GLdouble)x, (GLdouble)y, 0.0,
            model, proj, view,
            &pan_x, &pan_y, &pan_z);
        gluUnProject((GLdouble)x, (GLdouble)y, pan_z,
            model, proj, view,
            &pan_x, &pan_y, &pan_z);
        pan_y = -pan_y;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

/* ppmRead: read a PPM raw (type P6) file.  The PPM file has a header
   that should look something like:

     P6
     # comment
     width height max_value
     rgbrgbrgb...

   where "P6" is the magic cookie which identifies the file type and
   should be the only characters on the first line followed by a
   carriage return.  Any line starting with a # mark will be treated
   as a comment and discarded.  After the magic cookie, three integer
   values are expected: width, height of the image and the maximum
   value for a pixel (max_value must be < 256 for PPM raw files).  The
   data section consists of width*height rgb triplets (one byte each)
   in binary format (i.e., such as that written with fwrite() or
   equivalent).

   The rgb data is returned as an array of unsigned chars (packed
   rgb).  The malloc()'d memory should be free()'d by the caller.  If
   an error occurs, an error message is sent to stderr and NULL is
   returned.

*/
unsigned char* 
ppmRead(char* filename, int* width, int* height)
{
    FILE* fp;
    int i, w, h, d;
    unsigned char* image;
    char head[70];          /* max line <= 70 in PPM (per spec). */

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
    perror(filename);
    return NULL;
    }

    /* grab first two chars of the file and make sure that it has the
       correct magic cookie for a raw PPM file. */
    fgets(head, 70, fp);
    if (strncmp(head, "P6", 2)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not a raw PPM file\n", filename);
    return NULL;
    }

    /* grab the three elements in the header (width, height, maxval). */
    i = 0;
    while(i < 3) {
    fgets(head, 70, fp);
    if (head[0] == '#')     /* skip comments. */
        continue;
    if (i == 0)
        i += sscanf(head, "%d %d %d", &w, &h, &d);
    else if (i == 1)
        i += sscanf(head, "%d %d", &h, &d);
    else if (i == 2)
        i += sscanf(head, "%d", &d);
    }

    /* grab all the image data in one fell swoop. */
    image = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*w*h*3);
    fread(image, sizeof(unsigned char), w*h*3, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    *width = w;
    *height = h;
    return image;
}

textures(void)
{
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

/* XXX - RE bug - must enable texture before bind. */
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
   texture = (GLubyte*)ppmRead(texnames[0], &w, &h);
//   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, w, h, 0,
//   GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture);
   gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, w, h,
             GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture);
   free(texture);

/* XXX - RE bug - must enable texture before bind. */
   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int buffering = GLUT_DOUBLE;
    struct dirent* direntp;
    DIR* dirp;
    int models;

    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    while (--argc) {
        if (strcmp(argv[argc], "-sb") == 0)
            buffering = GLUT_SINGLE;
        else
            model_file = argv[argc];
    }

    if (!model_file) {
//        model_file = "data/dolphins.obj";
        model_file = "data/boeing_2.obj";
    }

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | buffering);
    glutCreateWindow("Smooth");

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);

/* Image data packed tightly. */
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    textures();

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
//    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    models = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    dirp = opendir(DATA_DIR);
    if (!dirp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open data directory.\n", argv[0]);
    } else {
        while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
            if (strstr(direntp->d_name, ".obj")) {
                entries++;
                glutAddMenuEntry(direntp->d_name, -entries);
            }
        }
        closedir(dirp);
    }

    glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Smooth", 0);
    glutAddMenuEntry("", 0);
    glutAddSubMenu("Models", models);
    glutAddMenuEntry("", 0);
    glutAddMenuEntry("[w]   Toggle wireframe/filled", 'w');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[c]   Toggle culling on/off", 'c');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[n]   Toggle face/smooth normals", 'n');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[b]   Toggle bounding box on/off", 'b');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[p]   Toggle frame rate on/off", 'p');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[t]   Toggle model statistics", 't');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[m]   Toggle color/material/none/texture mode", 'm');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[r]   Reverse polygon winding", 'r');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[s]   Scale model smaller", 's');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[S]   Scale model larger", 'S');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[o]   Weld redundant vertices", 'o');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[+]   Increase smoothing angle", '+');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[-]   Decrease smoothing angle", '-');
    glutAddMenuEntry("[W]   Write model to file (out.obj)", 'W');
    glutAddMenuEntry("", 0);
    glutAddMenuEntry("[Esc] Quit", 27);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

    init();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glTranslatef()` *multiples* the translation transform by the current matrix.  Your code seems to be assuming that it *overwrites* the the current matrix.

Push, translate, draw, pop:

```
if(spheres){
    i=0, j=0;
    while (1){
            printf("%d : %f %f %f\n", j, model->vertices[i], model->vertices[i+1], model->vertices[i+2]);
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(model->vertices[i], model->vertices[i+1], model->vertices[i+2]);
            glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            glutSolidSphere(0.4, 5, 5);
            glPopMatrix();
            if(j >= model->numvertices)
                break;
            i=i+3;
            j++;
        }
}
```